# Usb udev rule never worked for me

Tags: udev

I try to have a USB device recognized as being part of my user group. So I don't have to issue a `sudo` during development time when I debug my program which access those devices. Especially painful when using Netbean or Eclipse.

The udev rules never worked :

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/40-usbio.rules
SUBSYSTEM==”usb”, ENV{DEVTYPE}==”usb_device”, MODE=”0664”, GROUP=”odroid”,
ATTR{idVendor}==”04d8”, ATTR{idProduct}==”003f”
```

I also tried with mod `MODE=”0666”` and `MODE=”0777”`.

The weirdest part is that my USB camera has the same privileges and is part of the same group(root). But it never requires a `sudo` when I use `cheese` nor `camorama`.

```
ls -l /dev/bus/usb/001/013  ---------------> camera
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 12 Mar 16 21:25 /dev/bus/usb/001/013

ls -l /dev/bus/usb/002/007 ----------------> usb device
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 134 Mar 16 21:32 /dev/bus/usb/002/007
```

I also want to do the same with an arduino, but even with the proper rule file, it just does not work. Even after restarting udev or the computer.

How to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, You should accept Sylvain Pineau. See https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

I'd add a `NAME="my_device"` in order to create the corresponding node.

And check your quotes, replace `”` by `"`. It could be just that.

Comment: thx i cant believe i did not see the " problem
it works :-)

Comment: Don't forget to vote/mark your question as answered please.