# UDEV rules for FTDI not completely working

Tags: usb, permissions, udev

I know this question has been asked many times but I cannot make it work. I have a FTDI serial-usb converter. I have generated `10-fhss-usb.rules` in `/etc/udev/rules.d/`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", ATTRS{serial}=="FTTA5DMA", SYMLINK+="fhss", GROUP="dialout", MODE="0777", RUN+="echo USB CONNECTED!"
```

I have also added my user to `dialout` group:

sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER

and `groups $USER` returns:

```
jvgomez : jvgomez adm dialout sudo plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

(The plugdev group was created following another post) Now, when I connect the USB, running `ls -al` I can see:

```
$ ls -al /dev/fhss
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Jun  4 17:13 /dev/fhss -> ttyUSB0

$ ls -al /dev/ttyUSB0 
crw-rw-r-- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Jun  4 17:13 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

The `echo USB CONNECTED!` message is never displayed. And when I use `screen /dev/fhss/` it immediately says `[screen is terminating]`. To make it work, I sill have to run `chmod`

```
$ sudo chmod a+rwx /dev/fhss
```

And now:

```
$ ls -al /dev/ttyUSB0 
crwxrwxrwx 1 root dialout 188, 0 Jun  4 17:13 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

1) What am I missing? I still have to run chmod which is what I am trying to avoid. 
2) What is the difference between using `SUBSYSTEM=="tty"` and `SUBSYSTEM=="usb"`?

Any help is welcome!

EDIT: adding NAME="my_device" as proposed in [Usb udev rule never worked for me](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435348/usb-udev-rule-never-worked-for-me) didn't change anything.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution?

Comment: @Goddard I have it working yes, although the udev rule is exactly the same as posted (with `NAME="my_device" `). I cannot tell what I did to make it work, I cannot remember, sorry!

Answer (score 3):

I use a FT232RL chip in Bit Bang mode and ran into the same permission issues.
The rules suggested above did not work for me for reasons I do not understand.
However, with some modification I got it working.

Hopefully this can be of help to someone:

`$ lsusb`:

`Bus 001 Device 023: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC`

As above, I added the user to `dialout` and `tty`:

`$ sudo usermod -aG dialout $USER
$ sudo usermod -aG tty $USER`

But, the line in `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-libftdi.rules`, is different:

`ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS={idProduct}=="6001", OWNER="user", MODE="0777", GROUP="dialout"`

It could be that the crucial difference is `SUBSYSTEM=="usb"`.

Comment: It worked for me. You can substitute `ATTRS="idProduct"` with `ATTRS{idProduct}` though, as in `idVendor`.

Answer (score 2):

To make a FTDI breakout work on Ubuntu:

Open the file /etc/group with root permissions:

```
sudo nano /etc/group
```

After that, search for `tty:x5:` and `dialout:x20:`

Add your user to this groups typing your username in front of each line:

`tty:x5:<user>`

`dialout:x20:<user>`

You can also use the next two commands to avoid search for the file:

```
sudo usermod -aG tty <user>
sudo usermod -aG dialout <user>
```

Where `<user>`, is your user name.

Finally, reboot your computer.

If you want to use udev rules, connect the FTDI Module, then run:

```
lsusb
```

This will show the vendorID and the productID. For example:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
```

Where 8087 is the vendorID, and 0024 the productID.

Then, create a rule like this:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}="8087", ATTRS{idProduct}="0024", MODE="0660", GROUP="dialout"
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for all the time. I had got the "ftdi" driver as part of my linux kernel (/usr/share/hwdatausb.ids) to detect the vendor ID available and could confirm that "udev rules" had my Vid and Pid. But still, the driver wasn't detected the connection. THis was the trick ! Thanks @Gtronick !!

Comment: There's a typo, it should be `ATTRS{idVendor}="8087", ATTRS{idProduct}="0024", MODE="0660", GROUP="dialout"`, instead of the second "ATRRS".