# Can't Read and write from FTDI device

Tags: usb, permissions

I have a device that I am connecting to it successfully from windows application using a D2XX driver,
I am trying to connect to it now from Ubuntu OS   ( version 15.04) without success till now.

I installed the D2XX driver.

I did : `sudo rmmod ftdi_sio`
And : `sudo apt-get remove brltty`

(`sudo rmmod usbserial` said there is no device like that)

I also added the function `FT_SetVIDPID(0x0403, 0x6014` 0 to my code

( I took the numbers from the `lsusb` command output)

I also set the permission to read and write (666) for the com port /dev/bus/usb/001/???

At last I manages to open the port , could write a command to it but did not get any data back ( the FT_Read function receives 0 bytes after timeout)

In the past I managed to connect to the device from a VirtualBox loaded with Debian.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install FTDI drivers on Ubuntu. Follow this thread: [FDI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632261/udev-rules-for-ftdi-not-completely-working). This shows you an easy way to make the FTDI work on ubuntu.